# JToolbar added to JScrollPane will scroll when I put focus on a JButton on a Toolbar

Tags: java, swing, toolbar, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

How do I avoid having the JScrollPane scroll that has a JToolbar added to it that has buttons when I have already scrolled to where I want to go? If I move my mouse over a Jbutton on the toolbar (I disabled the scrollpane scrollbars and disabled autoscroll for both the JToolbar and the JScrollPane) the first Jbutton I move the mouse over highlights then the whole JToolbar moves right till the last button is lined up with the right side edge of the visible area of the JScrollPane.

Also as a clue possibly to the root cause of the problem I noticed on a different JToolbar in my application if I put focus on a button by moving the mouse over the button it causes the toolbar in another window to scroll if it was already scrolled.

I am trying to implement a scrollable toolbar and if you know of a implementation that works please let me know.

Thanks,
-Tony

Comment: I have an idea how can I write that, but nobody see to your monitor, please post your code in http://sscce.org/ form